# how to send interrupt or signal between two threads?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, ipc

I want to know about some sample progrmas in which some interrupts or signal which are communicated between two threads.I have surfed and found some system call like kill, tkill, tgkill and raise.But my requirment is not to kill the process it should behave as interrupt.In my code I have this blocking call.

```
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,0);
   read(fd,&dataReceived.Serial_input,1);
```

Any sample code which is similar to my requirement. pls do share.Thanks in advance

My code:

```
    void *serial_function(void *threadNo_R)
   {
   int ImThreadNo = (int) threadNo_R;
   fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);//
   if (fd == -1)
     {
    /* Could not open the port. */
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB1 - ");
     }
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,0);
    while(1)
    {
    read(fd,&dataReceived.Serial_input,1);
    printf("\n From serial fn: Serial_input is:%c\n",dataReceived.Serial_input);       
    dataReceived.t2=dataReceived.Serial_input;  
     if(V_buf.power_window_data.front_right_up>=1)
     {
        sprintf(cmd,"Window is  raising=%d",V_buf.power_window_data.front_right_up);
        do 
        {
            writenornot = write( fd, &cmd[spot], 1 );
            spot++;
        } while (cmd[spot-1] != '\0' );
        spot=0; 
        //
        if (writenornot < 0)
        {
        printf("Write Failed \n");
        }
        else
        printf("Write successfull \n");    
    // write( fd,"DOWN",4);

     }  
       print_screen=1;
    }
  }
```

Receive Func:

```
void *receive_function(void *threadNo_R)
{  
int ImThreadNo = (int) threadNo_R;

  while(1)
  {   
    if(msgrcv(R_msgid,&V_buf,sizeof(struct vehicle)+1,1,0)  == -1)
    {
        printf("\n\nError failed to receive:\n\n");
    }   
  }
}
```

I want to send signal  from receive function which should be handled by Serial function.

Comment: You will be happier in the long run with non-blocking IO and `select`, but for minimal changes to the code you already have, `tkill` is what you want - you just have to install a _handler_ for `SIGUSR1`, set to _not restart_ system calls, and there you are.

Comment: how to install handler SIGUSR1?

Comment: You should be able to answer that question for yourself.  Start by reading the `sigaction` manpage.

Comment: yeah will take a look @zwol

Comment: kill does not kill the process - it just sends a signal.  Why are you sending interrupts between threads when there are lots of other IPC mechanisms available.  Also, if there are two or more threads that have nominated themselves as the signal handler and they all do different things, how do you tell which one is handling it?

Comment: Use [`pthread_kill()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html). Because you are using devices and not normal files, `select()` alone would be insufficient/not-very-robust (to verify the device is ready); you'd also need to make the descriptors nonblocking. In some cases, like half-duplex serial comms, using a blocking thread and a timeout signal (some realtime signal, say `SIGRTMIN+0`) that has a handler installed (an empty function is fine), yields more robust code. The delivery of a signal will reliably interrupt blocking reads and writes to/from any character device.

Answer (score 1):

Your `serial_function()` is full of calls to functions that are not async-signal-safe.  It is completely unsuitable for use as a signal handler or for being called from one.

It would be possible to set up a thread in which `serial_function()` runs asynchronously, on demand, but that seems not to meet your objective of interrupting your `read()` call.

You could maybe set up a signal handler that itself notifies a thread in which `serial_function()` is waiting to proceed, instead of running that function in the thread that receives the signal.  it's unclear whether that would meet your needs.

Alternatively, you could possibly catch `EINTR` errors from your `read()` and call `serial_function()` directly in response.  Beware, however, that this alternative would not result in `serial_function()` running in the event that `read()` is interrupted after having successfully transferred any data (in the current call).

In any case, you can raise a signal in the thread of your choice via `pthread_kill()`, but you'll have to sort out your strategy before that's useful.